# Hide and Show Column feature in SAPUI5 table

Tags: sapui5

I would like to create one toolbar button in the table which could control the hide and show columns. For example, I have 25 columns , I want to give this choice to the user so that he/she could decide which columns need to be displayed.

Is this possible?

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is surely possible with [sap.m.TablePersoController](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.TablePersoController.html).

This control allows you to personalize your table's current view. It provides `Dialog` from which you can select columns to be displayed from all available list of columns.

[Here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TablePerso/preview) is demo.